# Cannot understand Courant's proof in his book

Tags: epsilon-delta

On pages 327 and 328 in R. Courant's book [What Is Mathematics](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=_kYBqLc5QoQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) the global continuity of the function $x \to \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ is shown. But I don't understand that proof which runs essentially as follows:

On finding
$$|f(x) - f(c)| = |x-c|\frac{|x+c|}{(1+x^{2})(1+c^{2})}$$
he says we can restrict $x$ to a fixed interval $|x| \leq M$
with $M$ an arbitrarily selected number. Then he says for $|x|, |c| \leq M$ we have
$$|f(x) - f(c)| \leq |x-c|2M < \delta 2M\leq \epsilon$$.

Two things that I don't understand here are:

1) Why can we first choose $M$?

2) Why can we ignore the denominator?

What have I missed?

Comment: The arbitrary choice of $M$ is necessary for the general proof. You ignore the denominator to get the crude (yet still sufficient) upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|x+c| \leq |x| + |c| \leq M + M = 2M$, and $1+x^2 > 1$, $1 + c^2 >1$, and take $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2M}$, then conclusion follows.

Comment: I am not sure if so then $M$ is independent or dependent? Will you please show me the logical form with quantifiers appearing?

Comment: @Comeseeconquer Fix $M$ (for all $M$ - we want $M$ large). Let an opponent choose $\epsilon$ (for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ - our opponent wants $\epsilon$ small) then we can choose $\delta$ (there exists $\delta$) - note that big $M$ and small $\epsilon$ mean that $\delta$ is small - the bigger the challenge, the smaller $\delta$ has to be.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Thanks. So it begins with: For every real $M > 0$ and every $\epsilon >0$ and every real $c$ there is a $\delta > 0$ ...? That is, $M$ is independent in this context?

Comment: @Comeseeconquer Indeed, and that is important, because it means we can establish continuity over as large a region as we like.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Thank you so much, I think I get it. One more question: So can I prove the global continuity of $1/x$ by the following: Fix any real $M > 0.$ Then for $|x|, |c| \geq M$ we have $$\frac{|x-c|}{|xc|} \leq \frac{|x-c|}{M^{2}} < \frac{\delta}{M^{2}} \leq \epsilon,$$ so $\delta := M^{2}\epsilon$ suffices?